# Getting a SIGABRT error when deleting a tableView row with UIAlert

Tags: swift, xcode, uialertcontroller

I'm trying to delete a row in my tableView with the commit editingstyle func. When the user deletes a row, I want that a UIAlertController is shown.
I tried it without the Alert, that works. 
Here is my commit editingStyle function:

```swift
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            if editingStyle == .delete {
                let sheet = UIAlertController(title: "Diesen Verein löschen?", message: "Wollen Sie diesen Verein für immer löschen?", preferredStyle:.alert)
                present(sheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
                let action1 = UIAlertAction(title: "Löschen", style: .default , handler: { (action) in
                    self.deleteClub(at: indexPath)
                })
                let action2 = UIAlertAction(title: "Abbrechen", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
                    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                })
                sheet.addAction(action1)
                sheet.addAction(action2)

                present(sheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
```

Here is my delete function, but I don't think, that here is an error, because it works without the Alert.

```swift
func deleteClub(at indexPath: IndexPath){
            let club = clubs[indexPath.row]

            guard let managedContext = club.managedObjectContext else {
                return
            }
            managedContext.delete(club)

            do {
                try managedContext.save()

                clubs.remove(at: indexPath.row)

                tableViewClub.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
            } catch {
                print("Could not delete")

                tableViewClub.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you have an error message in console when it crashes? Also with is `present(sheet, animated: true, completion: nil)` called twice?

Comment: Move your alert code from UITableViewCellEditingStyle to deleteClub func and then try again.

Comment: @aBilal17 that didn't change anything but thanks  that your tried to help :D

Comment: @Larme Oh yes I deleted it once and now it works :D

Comment: FYI, if you would have read the console, you would have got "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modally an active controller", which is an explicit error. Train yourself to force you to read them. if you don't understand them, search, or ask. But read them that's part of your job.

Comment: @Larme Yes that is my first app. I made it for fun for school just to try something new. But thank you very much.

Comment: Well I said that also, because it might be quicker to read the message and search for it, understand it than post a question and wait for someone to spot your mistake.